# Hiding A Notyfy Message

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the Notyfy jQuery plugin to add a message to the user displaying an error or success message for a delete action that was made by the user.

My question is I'm looking on the plugin documentation and wondering how I can set a time limit for it to hide the message.

http://craga89.github.io/notyfy/

Comment: Yes you can. There is an option called timeout for that. Set to false to make it sticky. Or setto number for ms of delay to close: timeout: 500

Comment: I thought I tried that and it wouldn't close. What does the timeout set it to seconds.

Comment: can you share the code that opens your message?

Comment: I do apologize when I had tried it my code wasn't in the best working form and so now i just need to figure out the number of milliseconds or what not to set it to

Comment: `timeout: false, // delay for closing event. Set false for sticky notifications`, change it to a number of ms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to adhead to Sheikh Heera's advice and set the timeout to how many milliseconds that I need for my message to display for.